# Rails 4 - Can't save model without creating new nested model with 'has_one' association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have a Visibility model, which has some boolean attributes and other things defining how other models can be seen.  Visibility is polymorphic, because I want it to belong to both the User and Activity models.  Visibility:

```
class Visibility < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :viewable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

User (edited to include totality):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Relations
  #has_many :posts
  has_one :fb_connection
  has_many :activities
  has_many :participations
  has_many :activities, :through => :participations
  has_one :visibility, as: :viewable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :visibility

  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
  has_many :sent_friend_invites, :through => :friendships
  has_many :received_friend_invites, :through => :friendships

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  # Callback to set a user's default visibility for their activities
  before_save :default_values

  # paperclip helper method
  has_attached_file :profile_pic, styles: {
    thumb: '100x100>',
    square: '200x200#',
    medium: '300x300>'
  }, default_url: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/743320/q_silhouette.gif"


  # Pagination
  paginates_per 100

  # Validations
  # :email
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates_format_of :email, with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i

  # Paperclip validation
  validates_attachment :profile_pic, :size => { :in => 0..10.megabytes }, :content_type => { :content_type => /^image\/(jpeg|png|gif|tiff)$/}

  def self.paged(page_number)
    order(admin: :desc, email: :asc).page page_number
  end

  def self.search_and_order(search, page_number)
    if search
      where("email LIKE ?", "%#{search.downcase}%").order(
      admin: :desc, email: :asc
      ).page page_number
    else
      order(admin: :desc, email: :asc).page page_number
    end
  end

  def self.last_signups(count)
    order(created_at: :desc).limit(count).select("id","email","created_at")
  end

  def self.last_signins(count)
    order(last_sign_in_at:
    :desc).limit(count).select("id","email","last_sign_in_at")
  end

  def self.users_count
    where("admin = ? AND locked = ?",false,false).count
  end

  def get_display_name
    if display_name =~ /./  # Just check that the display name is not ""
      #puts "display name: " + display_name
      return display_name
    else
      #puts "name: " +  [first_name, last_name].join(" ")
      return [first_name, last_name].join(" ")
    end
  end

  def get_profile_pic_thumb
    return profile_pic(:thumb)
  end

  def measurement_labels
    return I18n.t('user_label_use_metric_true') if use_metric      
  end

  private

  def default_values
    viewable ||= Visibility.create(default_viewable_params)  
  end

  def default_viewable_params
    {:public => true, :app_friends => true, :facebook_friends => true, :strava_friends => true, :viewable => self }
  end
end
```

Activity (relevant parts):

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...  
    has_one :visibility, as: :viewable, dependent: :destroy
    ...
end
```

I can't for the life of me get this to work.  Any time I just save a user model -- even if the Visibility model is not modified -- it creates a NEW Visibility model for the user.  E.g., in the console:

```
user = User.find(5)
user.foo = false
user.save
```

I get this output:

> (0.4ms)  BEGIN   SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "visibilities" ("public",
>   "app_friends", "facebook_friends", "viewable_id", "viewable_type",
>   "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)
>   RETURNING "id"  [["public", "t"], ["app_friends", "t"],
>   ["facebook_friends", "t"], ["viewable_id", 5], ["viewable_type",
>   "User"], ["created_at", "2015-10-23 23:06:57.431922"], ["updated_at",
>   "2015-10-23 23:06:57.431922"]]    (21.3ms)  COMMIT  => true

And naturally, trying to update the Visibility model through User fails.  While it is updated, a new one is also created in its place.  Here is the applicable user_controller methods and view using simple_form_for:

```
#user_controller
def preferences
    @user = current_user
    if !@user.visibility
      @user.visibility = Visibility.new
    end   
end

def update_preferences
    user = current_user
    user.update!(user_pref_params)
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t('user_flash_update_success')
    redirect_to profile_path(user)    
end

private 

def user_pref_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:use_metric, visibility_attributes: [:id, :public, :app_friends, :facebook_friends])
end
```

---

```
<!-- preferences form -->
<%= simple_form_for @user, :url => update_preferences_path do |f| %>            
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :visibility do |v| %>
        <%= v.input :public, label: t('user_preferences_label_public'), as: :select, required: false %>
        <%= v.input :app_friends, label: t('user_preferences_label_app_friends'), as: :select, required: false %>
        <%= v.input :facebook_friends, label: t('user_preferences_label_facebook_friends'), as: :select, required: false %>     
    <% end %>
    <!-- Preference for system of measurement -->
    <%= f.input :use_metric, as: :select, collection: [[t('user_preferences_use_metric_true'), true], [t('user_preferences_use_metric_false'), false]], label: t('user_preferences_label_use_metric'),  include_blank: false %> 

    <!-- Submit button -->
    <%= f.button :submit, :label => "Save", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

This attempt at mass assignment gives me this feedback:

> Started PATCH "/users/updateprefs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-23
>   17:02:52 -0700 Processing by UsersController#update_preferences as
>   HTML   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"FXj3kWxNDE7tl7InvBvL68UzlvmWR/d3aJ4/gTg7cCCEGEafJJZO10ud31kU2120SdKF3aNj5gy0FiizURHTeQ==",
>   "user"=>{"visibility_attributes"=>{"public"=>"false",
>   "app_friends"=>"false", "facebook_friends"=>"false", "id"=>"64"},
>   "use_metric"=>"true"}, "commit"=>"Update User"}   User Load (0.4ms) 
>   SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY
>   "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 55]]    (0.3ms)  BEGIN   Visibility
>   Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "visibilities".* FROM "visibilities" WHERE
>   "visibilities"."viewable_id" = $1 AND "visibilities"."viewable_type" =
>   $2 LIMIT 1  [["viewable_id", 55], ["viewable_type", "User"]]   SQL
>   (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "visibilities" ("public", "app_friends",
>   "facebook_friends", "viewable_id", "viewable_type", "created_at",
>   "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id" 
>   [["public", "t"], ["app_friends", "t"], ["facebook_friends", "t"],
>   ["viewable_id", 55], ["viewable_type", "User"], ["created_at",
>   "2015-10-24 00:02:52.244397"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-24
>   00:02:52.244397"]]   SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "use_metric" =
>   $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["use_metric", "t"],
>   ["updated_at", "2015-10-24 00:02:52.247304"], ["id", 55]]   SQL
>   (0.5ms)  UPDATE "visibilities" SET "app_friends" = $1, "updated_at" =
>   $2 WHERE "visibilities"."id" = $3  [["app_friends", "f"],
>   ["updated_at", "2015-10-24 00:02:52.250120"], ["id", 64]]    (13.3ms) 
>   COMMIT

As you can see, Rails is both creating a new visibility and updating the existing one!  I can maybe jerry-rig this to work around it with some really ugly code, but I would appreciate any help to keep my controller actions clean.

Comment: What is the rest of your `User` model like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `User` model, in the `default_values` method, you're creating a new visibility and assigning it to `viewable`.  However, this is scoped such that it is only available to the method, not the class as a whole (and thus does comparison against the method variable).

Also, `viewable` is the correct usage of the association only in the `Visibility` model.  In the `User` model, you will have to reference it as `visibility`.

What needs to be done is to use `self` to apply the comparison and assignment to the instance variable instead.

```
def default_values
  self.visibility ||= Visibility.create(default_viewable_params)  
end
```

Comment: You're a good good person.  It totally worked.  I was so frustrated by this that I completely overlooked that method.  Thank you!